# Error when installing turicreate

Tags: python, python-2.7, terminal, pip, turi-create

I'm trying to install a package called turicreate on my device. I want to use it in code written in python 2.7

I have both python 3.6 and python 2.7 on my device so I'm trying to use the command:

```
$ python2.7 -m pip install turicreate
```

and then I get this error:

```
Running setup.py install for prettytable ... error
Complete output from command /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/4d/3qphp3b56cjdhdqh3jcv994r0000gn/T/pip-build-Uya2Ub/prettytable/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/4d/3qphp3b56cjdhdqh3jcv994r0000gn/T/pip-3wU21B-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib
copying prettytable.py -> build/lib
running install_lib
copying build/lib/prettytable.py -> /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/prettytable.py'

----------------------------------------
Command "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/4d/3qphp3b56cjdhdqh3jcv994r0000gn/T/pip-build-Uya2Ub/prettytable/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/4d/3qphp3b56cjdhdqh3jcv994r0000gn/T/pip-3wU21B-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/4d/3qphp3b56cjdhdqh3jcv994r0000gn/T/pip-build-Uya2Ub/prettytable/
```

Could someone please propose a solution to this issue?

Thanks,

Abe

PS: I'm on Mac and doing this in terminal.

Comment: try `sudo python2.7 -m pip install turicreate`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error means that you do not have administrator permissions to write in the dictionary.  In order to gain this permission you need to use the [`sudo`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo) prefix.

```
sudo python2.7 -m pip install turicreate
```

Comment: Didn't work for Linux. However, by mac OS works fine. 
Why official documents are not correct and lead to issues?